# Can’t get wizard generated Xamarin / visual studio 2017 app to compile

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to make my C++ application cross platform and port it from MFC. The code base should be pretty portable but I am having problems getting something that works well. Xamarin looks promising it seems like I could put my C++ code into a library and call it from C# code but so far I can’t even get the most basic wizard created project to compile. 
I am on a windows 7 machine. I did a fresh install of visual studio 2017 community. I installed what I think are the correct components (see below) and had the wizard create a simple project. It then generates a long list of cryptic error messages. I am afraid I am not a C# programmer (if this looks promising I will have a reason to learn it). I have had some java android experience with android studio but never done NDK. So these are Greek to me and my web searches have not been fruitful. 
Does anyone have any idea what these messages mean?
In the wizard I made these choices:
1)  Visual C# Android 
2)  Android app (Xamarain)
3)  Single view app
4)  Android 5.0 lolypop
And I got these error messages, without adding a line of my own code:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Support' does not exist in the namespace 'Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?) App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   21  Active
>   Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Support' does not exist in the namespace 'Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?) App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   5   Active
>   Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Support' does not exist in the namespace 'Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?) App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   6   Active
>   Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'AppCompatActivity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   13  Active
>   Error   CS0115  'MainActivity.OnCreate(Bundle)': no suitable method found to override   App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   16  Active
>   Error   CS0115  'MainActivity.OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu)': no suitable method found to override App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   28  Active
>   Error   CS0115  'MainActivity.OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem)': no suitable method found to override   App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   34  Active
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'SetContentView' does not exist in the current context App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   19  Active
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'FindViewById' does not exist in the current context   App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   21  Active
>   Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Support' does not exist in the namespace 'Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?) App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   21  Active
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'SetSupportActionBar' does not exist in the current context    App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   22  Active
>   Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'FloatingActionButton' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   24  Active
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'FindViewById' does not exist in the current context   App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   24  Active
>   Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'FloatingActionButton' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   24  Active
>   Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MenuInflater.Inflate(int, IMenu)'    App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   30  Active
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'Snackbar' does not exist in the current context   App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   48  Active
>   Error   CS0103  The name 'Snackbar' does not exist in the current context   App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\MainActivity.cs   48  Active
>   Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    App1    C:\Users\Andre\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.csproj   1

I had android NDK (R15C) selected as well as Apache Ant (1.9.3) and C++ Android development tools

I did not select the emulator as I want to use my phone at this point. I also left out the other NDK versions. Do these correspond to the android version eg 5.0 lolypop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems VS can't find package `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` in your project. In Visual Studio go to **Tools** -> **NuGet Package Manager** -> **Manage NuGet Package for Solution**. Then choose **Browse** and search `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design`. Install it and rebuild your project.

Comment: Thanks
I tried this and I got a new error message though.
When I tried Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Package for Solution it said that Xamarin.Android>Support.Design  not available in this source.
It also says Each package ios licenced to you by its owner. NuGet is not responsible for, nor does it grant any license to, third-party packages. 
This tool is not working either. The installer says it was included. Though my searches mention something about windows 10. I run 7. The NeGet is under the universal windows package which seems to need 10.  Do I need windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

Last time, I upgraded VS & try test a xamarin app, I also faced this error. I goto Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings.
Check : Allow NuGet to download missing packages.
Check : Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio.
Then I rebuild app, NuGet check and download missing packages and build passed